# Alternative Socket IO Client

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to implement a device pairing program with nodejs. The server is implemented by someone else and uses socket io:

```
var http = require('http'),
io = require('socket.io');
```

But one of the devices that I am pairing does not support Websocket(HTML5). Is is possible to create a socket io client without using socket io, are there any alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try and catch, I have found that the browser that I am using, can not support buffering behaviour in Socket.IO.js . The first emit is done without buffering, therefore first pairing request can be emitted correctly. 
So I have changed Socket.prototype.setBuffer(true) to  Socket.prototype.setBuffer(false). This may not be a clean solution, but in my case it works.

Answer (score 1):

socket.io supports various transports such as flashsockets and XHR long-polling. So you do not have to use a different client - it should work out of the box even without Websocket support

Speaking of alternatives... there are some client libraries e.g. for Python but I don't think there are any that run in the browser - as I said before, there's no need for them.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. When I check server logs, I have seen my browser can only use jsonp polling transport. At first "emit" everything works fine but when I emit another message, there is nothing on server side debug logs. Do you have any idea, what the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure which types of fallbacks you'd like to use

```
io.configure("production", function() {
  io.enable("browser client minification");
  io.enable("browser client etag");
  io.enable("browser client gzip");
  io.set("transports", ['websocket', 'jsonp-polling']);
  io.set("log level", 1);
});

io.configure("development", function() {
  io.set("transports", ['websocket', 'jsonp-polling']);
});
```

you can see all the options here [`on the wiki`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)